# Woocommerce not displaying the correct related products (possible error within the code?)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm helping my dad with his website that sells industrial valves. Originally this was a website made by a company that suddenly closed one day and I was never able to reach them again. This is the reason why I can't understand completely how they built this website.

For some reason, one day the related products section, displayed in each product's page, stopped working. It displays products, but not **products by the same category**. Since then, I have been trying to understand how the code works and possibly fixing it without any results.

Link to page where the problem is (it's the same in any other product): http://vaportec-corp.com/en/product/a-x-premium-hose-assembly/

I have to point out two things:

1. Each product not only contains one, but **two** categories: the type
   of valve and the brand.
2. The slider is actually showing recently added products. Or well, the last ones I uploaded months ago. I just added one more product for test and it showed up there.

The code that displays the related products is the following:

```html
<section class="fondo-categoria"><!--Section slider productos category-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 category-title marginb20 margint20">
                <h1><?php _e('Mas productos por categor&iacute;a', 'mnt') ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

                <div id="owl-demo2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme marginb30 resize-margin">
                    <?php
                    wp_reset_query(); 
                    query_posts('post_type=product&posts_per_page=-1');
                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php 
                        if (has_post_thumbnail()){
                        the_post_thumbnail('catalogo', array('class' => "item "));
                    }
                        ?></a>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="prevcateg button-position-prevcateg"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ant.png"></a>
            <a class="nextcateg button-position-nextcateg"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/sig.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Hope you guys can help me with this one. Have a great day!

Comment: `query_posts` takes the same arguments as WP_Query, so go check the docs for that to see how to select posts by category (right now you are doing no such thing, so if this ever "worked" as you wanted it to, that was likely just coincidence.) https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query How to exclude posts (might not want to get the original product shown as "related" to itself) and define a specific or random order and maybe a limit, you can also find on that page.

Comment: @Gustavo I see the site (http://vaportec-corp.com/en/product/a-x-premium-hose-assembly/) right now and I see the products with the same category.